# Removing Vocals: Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro, vocals

I am trying to remove vocals from some songs in Logic Pro X.  However I have not yet been very successful.  If someone could help me it would be fantastic.

If you cannot remove vocals using Logic Pro X, Then would anyone have any other good software that they know will definitely remove them?

Comment: Removing a vocal from a finished stereo mix is quite similar to Philosophers turning lead into gold. Everybody wants to; no-one can really prove they did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I can think of removing the vocals is splitting the stereo track into its respective left and right mono channels. After that, invert the phase of one of the mono channels and you will get the vocals cancelled out. The downside to this is that there is a high possibility that it might change how the stereo track originally sounded like. Another point to keep in mind is that this method won't work if the vocals are panned left or right instead of being strictly centered.

Comment: Yea thanks. Tried that and it worked!  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!